# How do download response binary?

Tags: paw-app

In Paw, I have a POST request that returns a binary (excel file). How do I download it rather than see the binary output in the `raw` output.

Answer (score 13):

You can go to the `File` menu and pick `Export Response` then `Response Body`.

[image: Export a binary response from Paw]

Answer (score 1):

Use the curl exporter, and perform the curl request in your terminal of choice. Add a `-o yourfile.xlsx` option to the given command-line, and voila.